# CRM 2011: Insert condition to a fetchXML query using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have the following fetch XML query:

```xml
<fetch mapping="logical">
    <entity name="salesorder">
        <attribute name="salesorderid"/>
        <attribute name="new_type"/>
        <attribute name="new_solomonswonumber"/>
        <attribute name="new_resolutioncode"/>
        <attribute name="new_rentalsaleindicator"/>
        <attribute name="new_preferredphone"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="new_equipment"/>
        <attribute name="customerid"/>
        <order attribute="new_type" descending="false"/>
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="salesorderid" operator="eq" value="5AC5CBAC-25A0-E211-92B3-00155D815016"/></filter>
        <link-entity name="new_entity" from="new_entityid" to="new_entitylookup">
            <filter type="and">
                <attribute name="new_street1"/>
                <attribute name="new_province"/>
                <attribute name="new_postalcode"/>
                <attribute name="new_city"/>
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
    </entity></fetch>
```

I have a business need where I need to insert the following condition using java script:

```xml
<condition attribute='new_entityid' operator='eq' value='10ad18f6-c384-e211-b04d-78e3b50834b8'/>
```

So that the final fetchxml is as follow:

```xml
<fetch mapping="logical">
    <entity name="salesorder">
        <attribute name="salesorderid"/>
        <attribute name="new_type"/>
        <attribute name="new_solomonswonumber"/>
        <attribute name="new_resolutioncode"/>
        <attribute name="new_rentalsaleindicator"/>
        <attribute name="new_preferredphone"/>
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="new_equipment"/>
        <attribute name="customerid"/>
        <order attribute="new_type" descending="false"/>
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="salesorderid" operator="eq" value="5AC5CBAC-25A0-E211-92B3-00155D815016"/></filter>
        <link-entity name="new_entity" from="new_entityid" to="new_entitylookup">
            <filter type="and">
<condition attribute='new_entityid' operator='eq' value='10ad18f6-c384-e211-b04d-78e3b50834b8'/>
                <attribute name="new_street1"/>
                <attribute name="new_province"/>
                <attribute name="new_postalcode"/>
                <attribute name="new_city"/>
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
    </entity></fetch>
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks and best regards..

Comment: So is your question how to concatenate xml is Javascript? Or is your Fetch xml not working?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is why your fetch isn't working, it might be because you have your attributes nested in your  node.  Try it like this:

```
<fetch mapping="logical">
<entity name="salesorder">
    <attribute name="salesorderid"/>
    <attribute name="new_type"/>
    <attribute name="new_solomonswonumber"/>
    <attribute name="new_resolutioncode"/>
    <attribute name="new_rentalsaleindicator"/>
    <attribute name="new_preferredphone"/>
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="new_equipment"/>
    <attribute name="customerid"/>
    <order attribute="new_type" descending="false"/>
    <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="salesorderid" operator="eq" value="5AC5CBAC-25A0-E211-92B3-00155D815016"/></filter>
    <link-entity name="new_entity" from="new_entityid" to="new_entitylookup">
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute='new_entityid' operator='eq' value='10ad18f6-c384-e211-b04d-78e3b50834b8'/>
        </filter> 
        <attribute name="new_street1"/>
        <attribute name="new_province"/>
        <attribute name="new_postalcode"/>
        <attribute name="new_city"/>
    </link-entity>
</entity></fetch>
```

If the question is how do you insert you JS.  You can use a regex like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjmeyers/eG7F5/1/)):

```
var regex = new RegExp(/<link-entity.*name=[\"\']new_entity[\"\'].*>.*<filter[^>]*>/);

fetch = fetch.replace(regex, '$&' + newCondition)
```